# How can I escape being pinned by monsters?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I've been pinned down multiple times, I've also escaped in some cases, sometimes not. Since I have no clue how to escape I just buttonmash *every* button I can reach without moving my hands.

Since I got a quest today to beat up some huge crab who kept grabbing me, I need a solution to consistently get away if I want to beat that beast again. How do I evade being chewed on?

Comment: I'm surprised someone hasn't mentioned wiggling the analog stick; it can speed up how quickly the bar runs out.

Comment: Wiggling the stick does help, but I would recommend rotating it fast instead of mashing it left and right - that's how you break it off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get out of a pin instantly with dung bombs. You can use them even if you are pinned.

You can make dung bombs by combining dung + bomb casing. You can then multiply them in the wycoon.

It's a good idea to always carry some with you (they can also be used for relocating monsters).
Your palico companions will also sometimes throw dung bombs when you are pinned, but don't rely on that.

Comment: If you don't have any dung bombs however, repeatedly moving your circle pad will slowly free you from a pin. It is not efficient, but is a good backup for those without dung bombs.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a monster off you instantly by using a [Dung Bomb](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/dung-bomb). You make them by combining a [Bomb Casing](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/bomb-casing) and [Dung](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/dung).
You can multiply them at the Dundorma Town Market via Wycoon, but it needs to be unlocked first. The unlock path for the Dundorma Town Market is ([source](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MH4U:_Wyporium)):

1. Compelte 3 Star quest [Boulder Bash](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/quest/caravan/3/boulder-bash)
2. Complete the Honey Sweetens the Deal villager request ([Monster Fluid](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/monster-fluid) x1, [Glueglopper](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/glueglopper) x3, 1500pts)
3. Complete the Trading With the Town villager request [(Pale Extract](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/pale-extract) x3, [Lightcrystal](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/lightcrystal) x3, 2000pts)

Answer (score 0):

The circle pads produce a MUCH higher rate of escape than your buttons.  This also includes the right side circle pad in case of the New 3DS or Circle Pad Pro.

To test this, you can trigger a "mash button event" by fishing in the Dundorma commons, on the left side near the bridge.  Doing circles with both circle pads will catch the fish much quicker than any button mashing.